# Associate new Page Id with Sandbox Ad Account

Tags: facebook, sandbox, facebook-marketing-api

We are trying to associate a new Facebook Page with our sandbox account, as the previously associated page was removed. However, when we edit our sandbox account, we cannot find, or select, a Facebook page. There is also no option for creating a new Facebook Page as far as we can see.

How/where do we create/add a new associated Facebook page for our sandbox account? Is it even possible?

**Sandbox settings in Marketing API->Tools**
[image]

**Edit sandbox account->No pages available**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

We found a solution. We created a new Test Page for our Sandbox Test User, by following this guide: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-pages/

After the page was created, it was automatically associated with our sandbox account.